Not being able to connect to azure redis service
I have a webapp deployed in azure, and I´ve also configured a azure redis cache, but I am not being able to make my cache work. My nextjs frontend app is hosted in vercel.
This is my redis client in my nodejs app:
const redis = require("redis");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

// Variables de entorno para la caché
const cacheHostName = process.env.AZURE_CACHE_FOR_REDIS_HOST_NAME;
const cachePassword = process.env.AZURE_CACHE_FOR_REDIS_ACCESS_KEY;

if (!cacheHostName) throw new Error("AZURE_CACHE_FOR_REDIS_HOST_NAME is empty");
if (!cachePassword) throw new Error("AZURE_CACHE_FOR_REDIS_ACCESS_KEY is empty");

exports.connect = async () => {
  let client;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    client = redis.createClient({
      // Configuración de Redis para TLS en producción
      url: `redis://${cachePassword}@${cacheHostName}:6380`,
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true // Asegúrate de que este valor sea verdadero para requerir SSL
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Configuración local de Redis para pruebas
    client = redis.createClient({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379
    });
  }

  client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Cliente Redis conectado al servidor');
  });

  client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('El cliente Redis no pudo conectarse al servidor:', err);
  });

  client.on('end', () => {
    console.log('La conexión del cliente Redis se cerró');
  });

  await client.connect();

  return client;
};

My SSL port in the redis service is disabled and my SSL port is 6380, and the TLS version is 1.2
Everytime I make a request through postman or through my hosted app, the request stays in an infinite Sending request....
I have also tried with rejectUnauthorized: false and no changes were shown.
It seems that my redis client is connecting and failing connection in an inifinite loop:
Cliente Redis connected to the server
The Redis Client was not able to connect to the server: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
El cliente Redis no pudo conectarse al servidor: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Cliente Redis connected to the server
The Redis Client was not able to connect to the server: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
The Redis Client was not able to connect to the server: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Cliente Redis connected to the server

This is how I am handling redis in my controller method.
const { User } = require('../models');
const asyncHandler = require('../middlewares/async');
const { connect } = require('../redis/redis')

//@route    GET api/users/
//@desc     Get all users
//@access   Private
exports.getUsers = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
   const redis = await connect();

   const key = 'users';
   const redisUsers = await redis.get(key);

   if( redisUsers ) {
      console.log('Users From Redis')
      return res.status(200).json({
         success: true,
         data: JSON.parse(redisUsers)
      })
   }
      
   console.log('Users From DB')
   const users = await User.findAll();
   await redis.set(key, JSON.stringify(users));
   return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: users
   })
});

In my local environment if I connect to redis to port 6379 and to host localhost it works fine, but as soon as I try connecting to the service of redis in azure it fails.
In the network tab of the browser when I make a request going to a view that displays a list of users I get the request for long time with no status code and finally I get a CORS error but CORS is enabled from azure. Finally the response from my frontend is of type text/x-component instead of json.
Note: this error only occurs in requests that include redis in my server

Is your azure redis is open to the public network? You should try connect to your redis from your own pc to make sure. Why are you using azure redis instead of vercel redis? https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-kv

@yeya Yes it is open to the public network. I´ll take your suggestion on vercel redis, but why then vercel-kv instead of using redis in the server?

redis in what server? you use cloud services, so pick one and use it. It's not "best practice" to put the app in one cloud provider and it's cache in a second cloud provider

While trying your code and adding CORS in Azure, I encountered a CORS issue. We need to add CORS in your code using the CORS package in addition to the Azure CORS settings.
To reslove the issues with SSL/TLS configuration and CORS, Follow these steps

Add the configuration settings for the TLS protocol in Azure Cache for Redis.

Add cors to the node js code as shown in the below sample code



const  cors = require('cors');

// CORS configuration

const  corsOptions = {

origin: "*",

methods: ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE"],

allowedHeaders: ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept"],

};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));



I used this reference to Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS) Configuration in Azure Web app.



res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // Set the correct Content-Type header





I dont have in my config the End-to-end TLS encryption. I am using the C1 standard redis tier

Since you’re using the C1 standard tier, ensure that your Redis instance supports the necessary TLS configurations. If end-to-end TLS encryption isn’t available in your tier, you might need to consider upgrading to a tier that supports it.

The options on your call to .connect are incorrect. The host, port, and tls attributes need to be inside a socket property. This is a really easy mistake to make and I've done it myself several times.
This is probably the cause of your error in production and while it's not causing a problem for your local environment, it is still incorrect.
The code should look like this:
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  client = redis.createClient({
    url: `redis://${cachePassword}@${cacheHostName}:6380`,
    socket: {
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379
    }
  });
}

Now, you might be wondering why the local case is working even though I am claiming it was configured incorrectly. That's because localhost and 6379 are the default host and port for Redis. Node Redis looks for the socket.host and socket.port properties and if it doesn't find them, it uses the defaults.
This means that you could actually simplify the local code to just:
client = redis.createClient();

Either will work. And sometimes it's better to be explicit rather than implicit. No judgment either way.
If you run into similar things, the details on all the configuration options for Node Redis can be found in the client configuration guide on GitHub.
